# How to make this anchor tag clickable?

Tags: jquery, css, anchor

On a website I'm using right now there is a slider that pulls in random photos of different sizes. To keep the slider uniform and looking neat I through an image over top of the rotating images to act like a border, there is a hole that you can see the images through. It looks and works great. The person the website is for wants the images to be clickable, I tried putting the anchor tag on and when I click it leads no where because even though there is a hole in the image its acting as if there is something there. I have looked up how to fix this but I can't find any information anywhere.

Does anybody know if this is possible? I am willing to use jquery if need be but I'm stuck

```
    <div id="right">
     <div class="border-image">
     <img src="images/border.png" />
</div>
<div class="cyclepictures">
<div>
<a href=''><img src="" style="position: relative!important; margin: auto!important; padding-top: 30px;" /></a>
<a href=''><img src="" style="position: relative!important; margin: auto!important; padding-top: 30px;" /></a>
<a href=''><img src="" style="position: relative!important; margin: auto!important; padding-top: 30px;" /></a>
<a href=''><img src="" style="position: relative!important; margin: auto!important; padding-top: 30px;" /></a>
<a href=''><img src="" style="position: relative!important; margin: auto!important; padding-top: 30px;" /></a>
</div>

</div>
```

This is being generated through an image slider

Comment: Can you show code which demonstrates this?  Perhaps even a live example?

Comment: On click of the overlay, get the href of the anchor tag of the currently active image and do a window.location to said href. Otherwise, lose the overlay or split it into 4 pieces, top right bottom left.

Comment: did the solutions below work for you ?

Comment: sorry, no they didn't, not yet anyway, I'm still playing with it trying to get some response.

Answer (score 0):

JQUERY:

```
$('.border-image').on('click', function(){
    $('a.active').trigger('click'); // assuming your current image's anchor has active class.
});
```

As soon as the border-image is clicked, the currently active anchor/image's click is fired using the above. This is on the same lines as Ken suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you should add `onclick="window.location.href='#link'"` to your image:

```
<img src="#" onclick="window.location.href='#link'"/>
```

And you'll probably also want your mouse cursor to change as it does when hovering over a regular link, so you should add the`cursor:pointer`style attribute to the image.